# Dynamics CRM 2011 Server Groups for multiple instances

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm setting up a dev environment for CRM 2011, to test our organisation ahead of an upgrade from 4.0

I'm trying to avoid having to set up a separate DC for the dev environment as I only have limited resources to create VMs with.

Will 2011 use the existing 4.0 AD server groups, or will it create it's own groups?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to go the In-Place-Upgrade route, it will use the existing OUs.

Another option is to create a complete new Dynamics CRM 2011 environment (and therefore specifying a new OU). You can import your v4 Org-Database into it which will perform an upgrade. This gives you the possibility to test at least the database specific parts of the upgrade.

Comment: I have a copy of the org db that I'm going to be imported, I was just hoping to use the existing AD so I wouldn't have to set up a new AD environment. 

Do you know if CRM uses unique GUIDs for the server groups per instance?

Comment: @jim0thy you are able to use the same AD. You even are able to share the OU, as the generated groups are unique due to the environment-specific IDs. However, I wouldn't recommend this, as it is hard to determine which group belongs to which environment.

Comment: It's only going to be a temporary situation until I can convince the powers-that-be to give me some budget.

As long as I make a note of the existing GUIDs it should be okay.

Thanks.